# How can I add search option on UIPickerview in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, autocompletetextview

I am using UIActionsheet uipickerview in my project. Here, I am passing value according to his id. 
I mean, in uipickerview list it will show name, and after passing it takes its id.

So, for 5-10 values it is ok, but suppose I have more than 100 values with its id, then it takes to much time to scroll, find and select a value.

So, I want to add search option in it. So after clicking my Text Field that picker or pop up will come. And it shows some list first, as well as search option available there so user can type any one or two words, so according its words data will come according to word (auto search complete).

How can I implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Anyone wants it in swift...
Create a textField with name txtSearch and then in ViewDidload add below two lines

```
self.txtSearch.delegate=self
self.txtSearch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldValueChanged(TextField:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)

func textFieldValueChanged(TextField:UITextField)

{

    if((TextField.text?.characters.count)!>0)
    {
        self.filteredArray = (self.searchInArray(srchArray: self.ArraywithFullData, withKey: "key value", Characters: TextField.text!))!
    }
    else
    {

        self.filteredArray = self.ArraywithFullData.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
    }

    self.pickerView.reloadData()


}
func searchInArray(srchArray:NSMutableArray, withKey:String,Characters:String)->NSMutableArray
{

    let resultArray=NSMutableArray()
    for index in 0..<srchArray.count
    {
        let Dict  = srchArray[index] as! [String:Any]
        if let stringmatcher = Dict[withKey] as? String
        {
            if(stringmatcher.contains(find: Characters))
            {
                resultArray.add(Dict)

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

    }

 return resultArray

}
extension String {

func contains(find: String) -> Bool{
    return self.range(of: find) != nil
}
```

And For Objective-C You have to Do something Like below. But don't forget to call textField Delegates.

```
NSMutableArray *filteredArray;
NSMutableArray *ArraywithFullData;
self.txtSearch.delegate=self
[self.txtSearch addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
//

-(void)textFieldValueChanged:(UITextField *)TextField

{

    if((TextField.text.length)>0)
    {
        filteredArray = [self  searchInArray:ArraywithFullData withKey:@"key value" andCharacters:TextField.text];

    }
    else
    {

        filteredArray = [ArraywithFullData mutableCopy];
    }

    [self.pickerView reloadData];


}
-(NSMutableArray *)searchInArray:(NSMutableArray*)srchArray withKey:(NSString *)key andCharacters:(NSString *)charecters
{

    NSMutableArray *resultArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int index=0 ; index<srchArray.count; index++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *Dict  = srchArray[index];
        if ([Dict valueForKey:key] != nil)
        {
            NSString * stringmatcher = [Dict valueForKey:key];
            if ([stringmatcher containsString:charecters])
            {
                [resultArray addObject:Dict];

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

    }

    return resultArray;

}
```

Note if data is not in form of array of Dictionaries you can remove code work that is about dictionaries

Comment: Hassan Sir,  My code is in Objective c, so I am not able to understand above swift code, Can you post it objective c code(If you can) or else I will try to understand this code.

Comment: Updated the code Please check it. now it have both. Languages.... May be not Exactly but something like this you have to do.

Comment: congrats :) ..... now you can make it as efficient as u want i mean case sensitive etc....